# Использование временных таблиц SQL

Tags: sql

Я делаю заполнение таблицы в SQL. Создал временную таблицу, например

```
create table #sometable2 (id int,n int,m int,v int, b int)

SET @i=1
WHILE @i<=100
BEGIN
```

идет большой рабочий код на заполнение

вставка во временную таблицу

```
insert into #sometable2 values 
(@id,@n,@m,@v,@b)

SET @i=@i+1

END

insert into MyTable values 
(@id,@n,@m,@v,@b)

select * from #sometable2

order by sid

DROP TABLE #sometable2
```

отсортировал, а теперь мне нужно положить все эти данные в имеющуюся основную таблицу. Но проблема в том, что у меня в основную таблицу записывается не 100 строк например  (т.е. сколько их всего), а только 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы бы хоть синтаксис изучили....

MS SQL воспринимает ваши команды так:
1) Вставить в таблицу одну строку с перечисленными переменными:

```
insert into MyTable values (@id,@n,@m,@v,@b)
```

2) Выбрать записи из временной таблицы:

```
select * from #sometable2
order by sid
```

А на самом деле, как я понимаю, вы хотели вот этого:

```
insert into MyTable
select * from #sometable2
```

Comment: @minamoto,тогда такой вопрос, заполнение не происходит из-за следующей ошибки:The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "D_Sale_FK2". The conflict occurred in database "DB", table "dbo.D", column 'DId'. как-то получается что нет значений что ли?
причем если делать без временной таблицы, то эта ошибка тоже есть, но таблица заполняется без нескольких записей, а через временную таблицу нисколько записей не добавляется

Comment: Это значит, что вы пытаетесь вставить в таблицу данные, которые туда нельзя вставить - идет нарушение внешнего ключа. Одно из полей ссылается на другую таблицу, и вставляемые вами значения не находят соответствия в той таблицу.
Если вы делаете вставку напрямую в таблицу - каждая вставка проходит отдельным запросом, те записи, что имеют соответствие - вставляются, что не имеют - не вставляются.
Когда вы делаете вставку через временную таблицу - запрос один, и он либо выполняется полностью, либо не выполняется совсем, если хотя бы одна из строк не имеет соответствия.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял проблему, [вставку](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html) нужно делать так:

```
insert into MyTable select * from #sometable2
```